# Monogame template crashes on launch with System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, windows, monogame, xamarin-studio, assembly-resolution

Attempting to run this program on Windows

```
#region Using Statements
using System;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

#endregion

namespace asdf
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;        

    public Game1() //Exception raised points to here
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";              
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;       
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Exit();
        }       
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Raises the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000cc] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System.Drawing\System.Drawing\gdipFunctions.cs:127
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Icon.get_Handle () [0x00020] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System.Drawing\System.Drawing\Icon.cs:646
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Icon:get_Handle ()
  at OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinGLNative.set_Icon (System.Drawing.Icon value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at OpenTK.NativeWindow.set_Icon (System.Drawing.Icon value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at asdf.Program.Main (System.String[] arrayargs) [0x00000] in <
filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000cc] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System.Drawing\System.Drawing\gdipFunctions.cs:127
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Icon.get_Handle () [0x00020] in C:\cygwin\sources\mono\mcs\class\System.Drawing\System.Drawing\Icon.cs:646
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Icon:get_Handle ()
  at OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinGLNative.set_Icon (System.Drawing.Icon value) [0x00000]in <filename unknown>:0
  at OpenTK.NativeWindow.set_Icon (System.Drawing.Icon value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at asdf.Program.Main (System.String[] arrayargs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When run in Mono.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Mono
- Reinstalling Monogame
- Reinstalling Xamarin Studio
- Updating windows

and the error has remained unchanged.

This error does not occur when using SFML.Net in place of monogame

The whole solution can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?cvdvq32uw5uiwww)

Comment: Raises exception on what line?

Comment: Line 18, I marked it in the code.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide the full exception instead of just what you think is relevant, but I think I know what it is anyway.

Comment: That was the full exception as reported by Xamarin. Is there more info I can access?

Comment: Did you launch the app via mono.exe or simply double clicking? "When run in Mono.net." is an invalid statement, as your app should run by **Mono or .NET**, not both.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with Xamarin Studio (I use Visual Studio) but I assumed it would be possible to view inner exception detail.

Comment: @Lex Li Whoops, my mind got away from me. This does not occur when running in .Net and does occur in Mono.

Comment: If it's only basic, maybe zip and upload the entire project?

Comment: I can't even open that project. Are you by any chance building on and/or targeting Windows 8 / "Windows Store"?

Comment: No. It's a generated template from xamarin, iirc it's the same format as Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Fix:**

Make sure there aren't any incorrect mappings in the mono config file, ie remove any lines that look like this:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="whatever" />
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="whatever" />
```

**Explanation:**

If you look at the exception detail you'll most likely find an underlying `System.DllNotFoundException` being thrown because the parent `Game` class contains references to `System.Drawing.GDIPlus` which is exposed through `gdiplus.dll`. `gdiplus.dll` is a core .NET Framework library so it should already be in your GAC. The most common reason for being unable to load this with cross-platform frameworks like Mono is an invalid DLL mapping.

Comment: Where is the mono config file?

Comment: Speak of the devil, that page even includes a link specifically about dllmap in config: http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap

Comment: There is no information concerning dll maps in the mono config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Mono bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8309

Solution: in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.2.3\etc\mono\config", locate and delete the following lines:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
```

I can verify that this fixes the issue.

I would also suggest pinging on the bug report linked above to increase the chances of getting a fix in the near future.